# KNN | В чем смысл параметра weights со значением uniform

Tags: python, python-3.x, искусственный-интеллект

У knn есть параметр weights со значением uniform по дефолту

Какой смысл от этого параметра вообще, если весы для всех соседний одни и не зависят от расстояния

Answer (score 1):

Веса расчитываются во время обучения модели. [Параметр `weights`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) позволяет управлять тем как эти веса будут расчитаны:

> **weights : str or callable, optional (default = ‘uniform’)**
>
> weight function used in prediction. Possible values:
>
> **‘uniform’** : uniform weights. All points in each neighborhood are weighted equally.
>
> **‘distance’** : weight points by the inverse of their distance. in this case, closer neighbors of a query point will have a greater
>   influence than neighbors which are further away.
>
> **[callable]** : a user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the
>   weights.

Comment: Я спрашиваю о том, в каких случаях будет полезно использовать uniform.Просто мне кажется, что это значения параметра weights является бесполезным.В этом вопрос

Comment: @potemin, вы понимаете что написано в описании параметра `weights`?  Там как раз описан ответ на ваш вопрос ;)